# Fortran call from R: can't find what goes wrong

Tags: r, fortran90, subroutine

I'm trying to call a Fortran 90 subroutine from R.
I created the shared library using

`$ ifort -shared -fpic zerounoMatrix.f90 -o zerounoMatrix.so`

I call it from R code with

```
x_axis_pts<-seq(min(xy[,1]),max(xy[,1]),by=min(dx,dy))
y_axis_pts<-seq(min(xy[,1]),max(xy[,2]),by=min(dx,dy))

as.integer(length(x_axis_pts))->lxpts
as.integer(length(y_axis_pts))->lypts
as.integer(length(xy[,1]))->nrow_xy

Mzerouno<-matrix(0,nrow=as.integer(lypts),ncol=as.integer(lxpts))

dyn.load("zerounoMatrix.so")

Mzerouno=.Fortran("zerounomatrix",x_pnts=as.vector(x_axis_pts),
                                  y_pnts=as.vector(y_axis_pts),
                                  lxpnts=as.integer(lxpts),
                                  lypnts=as.integer(lypts),
                                  xy=as.matrix(xy,nrow=dim(xy)[1],ncol=dim(xy)[2]),
                                  nrow_xy=as.integer(nrow_xy))
```

the subroutine I call has this declarations:

```
subroutine zerounoMatrix(x_pnts,y_pnts,lxpnts,lypnts,xy,nrow_xy)

 implicit none
 integer, intent(in) :: lxpnts,lypnts, nrow_xy

 real, dimension(lxpnts), intent(in) :: x_pnts
 real, dimension(lypnts), intent(in) :: y_pnts
 real, dimension(nrow_xy,2), intent(in) :: xy
```

To test if the subroutine receive the correct input I print (inside the subroutine) the vectors I give to the fortran call but the values that are printed out are completely wrong. It seems it prints random variables.

There's no output because I want to try first if obtain the correct ingredients.

Comment: Reading the instructions can help. See `?.Fortran` and `?dyn.load`. -1 for not reading them (or reading them, but not following their instructions) before posting.

Comment: Ok, I read the arguments type section in `?.Fortran` but I misinterpreted i. Thanks.

Comment: Don't _just_ read the arguments section... read the _whole thing_. There are warnings about using Fortran 9x, and it suggests you read the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual, which tells you exactly what you need to do... and `?dyn.load` tells you to read `?SHLIB` in order to learn how to build suitable shared objects, which you don't do. In short, stop trying what you think should work and _read the instructions_.